# Estar de acuerdo con que/de que

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "estar de acuerdo con que", "estar de acuerdo de que" y "estar de acuerdo en que"?

También, ¿debo usar subjuntivo después de todas estas maneras?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Estar de acuerdo* puede ir [seguido por las preposiciones *con*, *en* o *sobre*](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/estar-de-acuerdo-de-o-con-algo-mejor-con-la-preposicion/). Es incorrecto usarlo seguido de la preposición *de*. También es incorrecto omitir la preposición cuando sigue una subordinada y decir **estar de acuerdo que*, aunque esta forma (que es un [queísmo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Que%C3%ADsmo)) es frecuente en la lengua informal.

El verbo en la subordinada que sigue a *estar de acuerdo (con/en/sobre) que...* puede ir en diferentes tiempos y modos verbales. Cuando el significado es el de "haberse puesto de acuerdo en hacer alguna cosa" se debe respetar la secuencia temporal y se suele usar el subjuntivo, aunque con el pasado se usa también el condicional:

- *Estamos de acuerdo en que se tomen medidas.* [presente → presente subjuntivo]
- *Estuvimos de acuerdo en que él viniera.* [pretérito perfecto simple → pretérito subjuntivo]
- *Estábamos de acuerdo en que él no vendría.* [pretérito imperfecto → condicional]

Cuando el significado de la expresión es más bien "pensar lo mismo sobre algún tema", las combinaciones válidas de tiempos y modos son más libres:

- *Estamos de acuerdo en que debemos seguir adelante.* [presente → presente indicativo]
- *Estamos de acuerdo en que debimos haber hecho algo.* [presente → pretérito perfecto simple indicativo]
- *Estamos de acuerdo en que estábamos equivocados.* [presente → pretérito imperfecto indicativo]
- *Estuvimos de acuerdo en que podríamos hablar.* [pretérito perfecto simple → condicional]

Comment: ¡Gracias! ¿Son correctas esas frases: "estamos de acuerdo con que la situación es grave" y "estamos de acuerdo con que tengamos que aceptar este trato" ?

Comment: La segunda debería estar en indicativo (*tenemos que aceptar*). No lleva subjuntivo porque la necesidad de aceptar es un hecho, no una hipótesis.

Comment: @pablodf76 - de acuerdo, pero Ashley, nota que en la versión negativa, sí iría bien con subjuntivo: No estamos de acuerdo con que tengamos que aceptar este trato.